# How to create folders in redis's cache with spring?

Tags: java, spring, caching, redis

I try to create folders in the redis cache of my project.
I want something similar to what spring automatically do with spring session.

[image]

I have a lot of "DisplayItem" entries and I want to store them in a "displayitem" folder.

Here is my code :

```
@Cacheable(value = "displayItem", cacheManager = "longLifeCacheManager")
public DisplayItem getDisplayItem(String displayItemCode) {
    // Do a lot of things
}

@Cacheable(cacheManager = "mediumLifeCacheManager", value = "preferences:userPreferences", key = "#zenithName")
public UserPreferences getUserPreferencesByZenithName(String zenithName) {
    // Do something
}
```

If I replace the value by "foldername:displayItem", it create a folder, but only for the keys (like I did for the preferences in the screenshot).
I don't find how to store all the values in this same folder.

How can I do this ?

Answer (score 2):

I finally found a solution.
In the configuration of the CacheManager, I need to set UserPrefix with True.

```
@Bean(name = "mediumLifeCacheManager")
public CacheManager mediumLifeCacheManager(RedisTemplate redisTemplate) {
    RedisCacheManager cacheManager = new RedisCacheManager(redisTemplate);
    cacheManager.setDefaultExpiration(redisExpirationMedium);
    cacheManager.setUsePrefix(true);
    return cacheManager;
}
```

Now this works like I want.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

it also works using keys with the semicolon separator like `<prefix>:<key>` will group all the key underneath the  folder (kotlin)

```
redisTemplate.opsForValue().get("folder-1:$key")
```

[image]